# How to restrict app for tablet in Android?

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

i want to my app run only mobile device not in the

> tablet 10 and 7 inch

. but my app is run on both tablet size .please help me out

Comment: You achieve this by declaring (or excluding) elements in your AndroidManifest. See the [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) manifest elements.

Comment: <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />

Comment: ii declared but no change in tablet installation.

Comment: What API level are you using? It's the density you're interest in. Check out the example on the compatible-screen link. The control over these things got much better post 3.1

Comment: @vabhavsingh please review my answer

Comment: It appears my answer was removed. How strange. The answer I provided directed the user to the purest source where they could easily see the answer should they have read it. I didn't feel the need to bulk it out with copy and paste from the dev guide that lacks context and formatting. Please restore.

Comment: @vabhavsingh - nothing you can do sorry. It'll be another user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes as @OceanLife says you Should Go with [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) or [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

but I would like to add Something here.

if you are using

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

then note what official [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) documentation says:

> if you want your application to be available only for large and
>   xlarge screen devices, the  element allows you to
>   declare that your application does not support small and normal screen
>   sizes. **External services (such as Google Play) will filter your**
>    **application accordingly. You can also use the** 
>    **element to declare whether the system should resize your application**
>    **for different screen sizes.**

So it will effect after you will upload your apk file to PlayStore. untill you will not get this feature affected.

Also see the [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) document for more information about how Google Play filters applications using this and other manifest elements.

Hope it will Help.

Answer (score 12):

The google developer has very detail information on that so please check this link:
**[Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)**

Quoting relevant parts below.

Handsets only:

> #### [Declaring an App is Only for Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps)
>
> ```
> <manifest ... >
>     <compatible-screens>
>         <!-- all small size screens -->
>         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
>         <!-- all normal size screens -->
>         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
>         <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
>     </compatible-screens>
>     ...
>     <application ... >
>         ...
>     <application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Tablets only:

> #### [Declaring an App is Only for Tablets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps)
>
> If you don't want your app to be used on handsets (perhaps your app
>   truly makes sense only on a large screen) or you need time to optimize
>   it for smaller screens, you can prevent small-screen devices from
>   downloading your app by using the  manifest element.
>
> ```
> <manifest ... >
>     <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
>                       android:normalScreens="false"
>                       android:largeScreens="true"
>                       android:xlargeScreens="true"
>                       android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
>     ...
>     <application ... >
>         ...
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: +1, this link was actually more useful than the other answers here, because it helped me understand when to use `<supports-screens>` vs `<compatible-screens>`. I took the liberty to quote relevant examples in the answer.

Comment: For Handset you have just set normalScreenSize, what if for device which has 5inch or 6inch? You mean normalScreenSize is just for phone?

Do u not think, u should set attributes for largeScreenSize?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on your android manifest file

```
    <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="6"
android:targetSdkVersion="8" />


<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: Think vabhavsingh is after the opposite @StarsSky but yea the ideas the same.

Comment: i want to my target sdk on jeelybean version

Comment: 8 to 16 sdk version for mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

You should use this `attribute` in your `mainfest`  **android:largestWidthLimitDp="enter mobile pixel value which above you want restrict."**

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="500"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

By using **Uses-Feature** it seems you can restrict the app distribution to only Landscape screen devices "tablets and tablets like devices".
Here is the code you will need in your manifest.xml:

```
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"
                      android:required="true"
          ></uses-feature>
```

Also use:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```