# How to preview which devices a requiresSmallestWidthDp config matches?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-screen-support

[As is well-known](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html), to limit Google Play distribution to devices with certain dimensions, you'd use `<supports-screens>` or `<compatible-screens>`, depending on your needs.

For example, to allow installation [only on 7" tablets or larger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270934/56285), you'd set `requiresSmallestWidthDp` to 600:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

My question is, is there any way to check, **in advance** (before uploading your APK to Play), which devices a specific config would match?

For example in my case, I currently support tablets and plan to gradually allow smaller devices, starting from 5.7" and 5" screens. Being able to preview what devices for example `normalScreens="true"` & `requiresSmallestWidthDp="360"` matches would be very useful.

*Afterwards*, of course, you can see this information directly on Google Play, in APK -> Device Compatibility.

[image]

But trial-and-error on Google Play would be clumsy, since it takes several hours after uploading a new APK for the changes to take effect.

**Alternatively**, is there any comprehensive resource for checking `smallestWidthDp` for common device models? It's a bit of a hassle to calculate it from raw pixel resolution & density (dpi) & screen size in inches every time. Googling `<device> smallestWidthDp` also gives surprisingly poor results.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you don't have to publish your app (and thus wait several hours) to see list of compatible devices. Couple of days ago I uploaded test app myself to see the list of devices supporting <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

Comment: @pelotasplus: Hmm, yeah, it actually dawned on me too that I could probably upload the APK to alpha/beta to see this info without actually publishing. You might add that as an answer, especially if no-one comes up with better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but you don't have to publish your app (and thus wait several hours) to see list of compatible devices.

Couple of days ago I uploaded test app myself to see the list of devices supporting

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

Just go to the https://play.google.com/apps/publish/, upload APK. Your app entry will be in Draft mode, not published, and there will be a link to supported devices.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/euvclc44lfsirsv/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-28%20at%2008.50.55.png

Comment: The link is broken